# How to use proper container in python

Tags: python, python-collections

For the following code I would like to use a structure in order to not have to give 2 values for each element min and max and also I would like to have a container if exists to can give one value and the other one to remain None. For instance power to have only min element. So for power to have a container with 2 elements (for min and max) and same for temperature. How is that possible in python ? please help, thanks!

```
def result_final(
    power_min,
    power_max,
    temperature_min,
    temperature_max
) -> str:
    def _result_min(value) -> str:
        return "<min>" "<value>" + str(value) + "</value>" + "</min>"

    def _result_max(value) -> str:
        return "<max>" "<value>" + str(value) + "</value>" +" </max>"

    def _measure_result(unit_id, min_value, max_value) -> str:
        return (
            "<measure_result>"
            "<unit-id>" + str(unit_id) + "</unit-id>"
            "" + _result_min(min_value) + ""
            "" + _result_max(max_value) + ""
            "</measure_result>"
        )

    def _stats(object, min_value, max_value) -> str:
        return (
            "<stats>"
            "<object>" + object + "</object>"
            "" + _measure_result(0, min_value, max_value) + ""
            "" + _measure_result(1, min_value, max_value) + ""
            "</stats>"
        )

    content = (
        '<result-stats>'
        "" + _stats("POWER", power_min, power_max) + ""
         "" + _stats("TEMPERATURE", temperature_min, temperature_max) + ""
        "</result-stats>"
    )
    return content

x = result_final(power_min = 12, power_max = 125, temperature_min = 12, temperature_max = 12)
print(x)
```

Comment: Could you explain what it is you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest just using tuples for each min/max pair:

```
from typing import Optional, Tuple

Stats = Tuple[Optional[int], Optional[int]]  # min, max


def result_final(power: Stats, temperature: Stats) -> str:
    def _result_min(value: Optional[int]) -> str:
        return "" if value is None else f"<min><value>{value}</value></min>"

    def _result_max(value: Optional[int]) -> str:
        return "" if value is None else f"<max><value>{value}</value></max>"

    def _measure_result(unit_id: int, value: Stats) -> str:
        min_value, max_value = value
        return (
            "<measure_result>"
            f"<unit-id>{unit_id}</unit-id>"
            f"{_result_min(min_value)}"
            f"{_result_max(max_value)}"
            "</measure_result>"
        )

    def _stats(obj: str, value: Stats) -> str:
        return (
            "<stats>"
            f"<object>{object}</object>"
            f"{_measure_result(0, value)}"
            f"{_measure_result(1, value)}"
            "</stats>"
        )

    return (
        "<result-stats>"
        f"{_stats('POWER', power)}"
        f"{_stats('TEMPERATURE', temperature)}"
        "</result-stats>"
    )


print(result_final((12, 125), (12, 12)))
```

Comment: is any way to can run result_final somehow to contain power.min ? like 
print(result_final((power.min = 12, power.max = None), (12, 12)))

Comment: You could use dataclasses or NamedTuples instead of regular tuples if you want each item to have a name.  If `Stats` were defined as a `NamedTuple` of `min` and `max` then you could call `result_final` as `result_final(power=Stats(min=12, max=None), temperature=Stats(min=12, max=12))`.  This doesn't make any difference to the generated output.  With the regular tuple form you can also say `result_final(power=(12, None), temperature=(12, 12))` if you want to.

Comment: Thank you so much, Samwise

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at Python `dataclasses`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyContainer:
    power_min: int = None
    power_max: int = None
    temperature_min: int = None
    temperature_max: int = None
```

The `dataclass` wrapper provides a convenient way to define a class that just stores some data. `dataclasses` is in the standard library (i.e., you do not need to install anything).
The class I defined, by default, uses `None` for all attributes. Or you can specify values for the attributes you need.

```py
a_container = MyContainer(power_max=5, temperature_min=3)
```

I also suggest to choose a better name than `MyContainer`: I used that because I did not know what you were trying to achieve!
You can also decide to define two separate classes for `TemperatureExtremes` and `PowerExtremes`, if that makes more sense for you!

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look on it